# jQuery Ui-Autocomplete in popover

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, popover

I want to use ui-autocomplete with bootstrap popover but the rendered html form in popover dialog is not able to detect any events(eg. click or focus). What is the solution for this??

JS Code for popover

```
this.postDialog.popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'New Post',
    html: 'true',
    content: _template,
    container: 'body'
});
```

JS code for autocomplete

```
 $(elementId).autocomplete({
        source: sourceDataFromArray,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
         //statements 
        }
});
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: after rendering html template in popover... button click event is also not working