# Google places API : pac-container display stays "none" in bootstrap popover

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google places API through geocomplete plugin (http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/), to get an autocomplete input field.
This field is put in a bootstrap popover. The problem is that the pac-container div is not "activated" when i start typing something in the field, ie. display stays "none".
When i put the field outside the popover, everything works fine.

Would you have any idea about the origin of such a problem ?

Many thanks!

Xavier

Comment: Seems to be a problem of [event detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143398/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-popover)...

Answer (score 2):

Its to do with bootstrap modal z-indexing competing with google map's search result z-indexing. Try this out in your css.

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4160).